# batch-rename using sets of consecutive numbers

Tags: bash, zsh, batch-rename

I have folders (in multiple dirs) named something like folder1 to folder9. Using `zsh`/`zmv` or `bash` I would like to rename these with another set of consecutive number e.g. 10-18, 19-27, etc.

```
# Create dummy data

#!/bin/zsh

for (( i=1; i<=9; i++)); do
   mkdir folder$i
done
```

Not sure how to go about it exactly...

```
folders=(*)

# Maybe something like 1:length-of-folders..?

for (( i=1; i<=$#folders; i++)) do
   zmv -n folder$i folder$i+9
done
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using bash, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
    mkdir foo$i
done    

for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
    mv foo$i foo$((i + 10))
done
```

but say you if have folders `foo1`, ..., `foo10`, and you need to move them to `foo3`, ..., `foo12`, then you need to "start at the tail" by first moving `foo10` to `foo12` first, and then deal with `foo9`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `zmv` is not useful if you don't pass a pattern, you might as well call `mv` directly.

To add 9 to each number, you can use

```
zmv '(folder)(<->)' '$1$[$2+9]'
```

but note that this relies on the range of numbers not overlapping.

In general, if you want to rename files to use consecutive numbering, you can let zsh increment the number by including something like `$[i++]` in the replacement text. Again, beware if the range of numbers might possibly overlap. You can avoid trouble by renaming to an intermediate pattern.

```
i=10; zmv '(folder)[0-9]##' '$1$[i++].consecutive'
zmv '(folder<->).consecutive' '$1'
```

If you want a non-default sorting order, you can use glob qualifiers. For example, to number files in the order of their modification time:

```
i=1; zmv -Q '(folder)[0-9]##(Om)' '$1-by-date-$[i++]'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will rename every file/folder inside current dir. The folders will be renamed as 18, 19 and so on.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
cd "dir/that/contains/folders/"
COUNTER=18;
for file in `ls`; do
    mv $file "folder"$COUNTER
    COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one of the `bash` comment I manage to solve it using `zsh` too... it's actually a piece of cake.

```
#!/bin/zsh
source ~/.zshrc

folders=(folder*)

for (( i=1; i<=$#folders; i++)) do
   zmv -n folder$i folder$(($i+9))
done

# Change the +9 to multiples of 9 to successively increase in steps of 9.
```